# Can't access dfs namespace over vpn

Tags: windows, vpn, dfs

I've recently configured 2 servers in AD on the same domain level. They are physically separated and permanently connected through a site-to-site vpn for dfs replication.

All well, but when users connect to either site through vpn (from home e.g.) they can't use the domain level method: \\domain.com\data
Internally this works perfectly, resolving domain.com when connected through vpn gets the correct IP.

I've tried Google to figure things out. What I was able to find was that more people have this issue, no real solution found though.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Especially a solution would be really helpful!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of interest, are you also running WINS on your network and are you handing WINS addresses to the VPN clients? In addition to this, even though there is address resolution, are you able to reach both DFS servers in question from the VPN? Are there appropriate routes from the VPN subnet to both sites?

Comment: We have WINS server on our AD server. No specific handling for as far as I know. Both DFS servers are reachable.

Comment: OP, can you tell us if the home VPN users are joined to the same domain, and if your VPN setup gives the clients the same DNS servers at home as they would be using while at work?

Answer (score 1):

[The DFS topology is stored in AD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb524801(v=vs.85).aspx). This means that non-AD joined computers (probably the home computer) won't be have access this information. Non-domain joined users will have to either connect via `\\explicitServerName\share` or will have to be joined to the domain.